# Error when creating new Unity projects and in all existing projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, cs0246

I'm getting the following error in all of my unity projects and the new projects I create. I can not find a solution for this. I even tried uninstalling Unity, Unity Hub and Visual studio. Then reinstalling but still same issue. I'm using Latest unity 2020 LTS version. I tried different versions and issue stays the same.

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.visualstudio@2.0.11\Editor\VisualStudioIntegration.cs(30,18):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Messager' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Messager is a part of the Visual Studio Editor package
> (Packages/com.unity.ide.visualstudio/Editor/Messaging/Messenger.cs).

It's likely the package `Visual Studio Editor` hadn't been installed correctly, re-install it through Unity's Package Manager. And check that you have `Game Development With Unity` package installed for the editor in Visual Studio Installer.